# Show given function is not integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The function $f$ defined on $(0,1)$ by

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, \rm{if \ x \ is \ rational} \\
\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor, \rm{if \ x \ is \ irrational} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Show that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \infty$

I'm not sure how to proceed in this. Just looking for some hints.

Edit: Since, irrationals are a set of infinite measure and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = \infty$, can we directly say, the integral will be infinite?

Comment: You do have $f = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n\cdot 1_{(1/(n+1), 1/n)}$ almost everywhere.

Comment: your argument isn't valid, as $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2} = 2 x^{1/2} |_{0}^1 = 2$.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=1/x-1$, $g(x)\leq f(x)$ almost everywhere and $\int_0^1g(x)=ln(x)-x]_0^1$.